# Calling the constructor and initializing

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, initialization

What is the main different of these 2 and why doesn't the second one work when like this?

```
template <class T> MyStack<T>::Node::Node(T& input, Node* head):next(head),value(input) {}

template <class T> MyStack<T>::Node::Node(T& input, Node* head) {next = head; value = input;}
```

My guess on why the second one doesn't work, is because it has nothing to assign variable when initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyStack<T>::value` looks like it is of type `T&`.  If that's the case, then remember that references must be initialized, and they cannot be rebound to a different object.  Using the initializer list is the only way to correctly initialize references that are object data members; you cannot initialize them with assignment in the constructor.  (In fact, if you omit the initializer list entry you should get some error similar to "uninitialized reference member.")

Comment: Great. Thank you for your answers and to you other guys as well.

Answer (score 0):

`next` and `value` might not have empty default constructors.

Besides that, const and reference members must be initialized in the initialization list, you can't assign to them.